# How to force browser to cache the page in websphere portal

Tags: websphere, browser-cache, websphere-portal

Can I force a browser to cache the pages responded by WPS 6.1?

Is force a browser to cache the pages a way to fulfill the requirement?

I've try to create a filter and config it in the wps.

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>Cache Filter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.samaxes.filter.CacheFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>expirationTime</param-name>
       <param-value>120</param-value>
   </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>Cache Filter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/portal/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

It is working, but the HTTP header is still:

Cache-Control   no-cache
Content-Language    en-US
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Fri, 11 May 2012 07:50:19 GMT
Expires Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
IBM-Web2-Location   ...
Pragma  no-cache
Server  WebSphere Application Server/6.1
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Vary    User-Agent,Cookie
How to get the correct response header?
Cache-Control : max-age=120 
Expires :

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should note about trying to cache whole pages is that the URL for a portal page is state aware. This means if you change the state of your portal session then even if you're on the same page it's going to be a different URL making cache difficult.

However here is a link about how to turn this type of caching on using mechanisms built into Portal. The author does make a note that even though he sees the cache entry in his browser and the proper cache header are, the browser is still making a request to the server.

http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-cache-portal-page-in.html

Edit:
Including a link to Portal 6 specific documentation on caching pages since I think the above blog is focused on Portal 7

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc/wpf/tune_cache.html